# tbody element breaking nth-child selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The code below should color the rows as follows:

1. yellow,
2. red,
3. yellow,
4. red,
5. yellow,
6. red … and so on…

This works as expected when removing all `<tbody>` and `</tbody>`.

But if using `<tbody>` and `</tbody>`, as in my code, the layout breaks. Seems like it starts again with yellow at every `<tbody>` block.

Unfortunately I need the HTML as it is, with `tbody`, so I cannot simply remove it.

Does anybody know a CSS workaround for this issue?

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-color: green;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.middle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.right {
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.boldtitle {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

td {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: dotted;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:751px) {
  .table_details {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Cars</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">GM</a><span class="link_company">GM & </span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">VW</a><span class="link_company">VW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">BMW</a><span class="link_company">BMW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Citroen</a><span class="link_company">Citroen</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Fruits</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Apple</a><span class="link_company">Apple</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Banana</a><span class="link_company">Banana</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Plump</a><span class="link_company">Plump</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: If you are going to split them in multiple tbody tags like that then shouldn't you just set the header as a different colour - this will then show the separation of the body tags and will allow for you not to bother hardcoding the styles as in the below answers.  If you need true alternative tr colours, then you would need to use js to calculate the alternates or remove the tbody (which you say you can't do)

Comment: @David is js solution out of question? Otherwise i don't think it is possible with today's standards

Comment: Hi @AdamK., yes, JS is out of question.

Answer (score 8):

Check if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/e0s6prcp/2/) meets your requirements.

Add CSS:

```
tbody:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}

tbody:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if an extra row <tr> is added to the first <tbody>

Comment: Added a bit of jquery to solve above issue. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/e0s6prcp/3/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the `nth-child` selectors relative to the `table` element, which ignores the `tbody` factor, make them relative to each `tbody` element, which allows you more control over their styling.

The solution below is based on your existing HTML structure, which contains an odd number of rows in the first `tbody`. If this changes to an even number you will need to adjust the selectors.

```
tbody:nth-child(odd) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd) tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

tbody:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
tbody:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-color: green;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.middle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.right {
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.boldtitle {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd) tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

tbody:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
tbody:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

td {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: dotted;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Cars</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">GM</a><span class="link_company">GM & </span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">VW</a><span class="link_company">VW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">BMW</a><span class="link_company">BMW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Citroen</a><span class="link_company">Citroen</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Fruits</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Apple</a><span class="link_company">Apple</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Banana</a><span class="link_company">Banana</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Plump</a><span class="link_company">Plump</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selectors so that the coloring doesn't include the first tr of each tbody:

```
tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-color: green;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.middle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.right {
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.boldtitle {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

td {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: dotted;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:751px) {
  .table_details {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Cars</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">GM</a><span class="link_company">GM & </span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">VW</a><span class="link_company">VW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">BMW</a><span class="link_company">BMW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Citroen</a><span class="link_company">Citroen</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Fruits</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Apple</a><span class="link_company">Apple</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Banana</a><span class="link_company">Banana</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Plump</a><span class="link_company">Plump</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the same thing you did with tr on the tbody

```
tbody:nth-child(odd) tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

tbody:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

tbody:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the result:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-color: green;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.middle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.right {
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.boldtitle {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd) tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

tbody:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

tbody:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

td {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: dotted;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:751px) {
  .table_details {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Cars</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">GM</a><span class="link_company">GM & </span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">VW</a><span class="link_company">VW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">BMW</a><span class="link_company">BMW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Citroen</a><span class="link_company">Citroen</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Fruits</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Apple</a><span class="link_company">Apple</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Banana</a><span class="link_company">Banana</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Plump</a><span class="link_company">Plump</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Careful if you use this on dynamic content as it won't work if the numbers of tr changes

Comment: This doesn't work if there is an extra <tr> added to the first <tbody>

Comment: @Chiller If I add a third `tbody` block it doesn't work any more. Why that?

Answer (score 0):

Since CSS4 standards are not yet conventional, you could simply use this small piece of js that i have written. (Vanilla, no jQuery needed - QuerySelector is majorly supported IE8+)

When triggered it will add even class to rows inside tables (ignoring table bodies)

```js
var Tables = document.querySelectorAll("table");//Find Tables in document
for (var i = 0; i < Tables.length; i++) {
  var Rows = Tables[i].querySelectorAll("tr");//find rows in each found table
  for (var j = 0; j < Rows.length; j++) {
    if (j % 2 !== 0) Rows[j].classList.add("even");//Even row - add class
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-color: green;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.middle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.right {
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.boldtitle {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

tr{
  background-color: yellow;
}
tr.even {
  background-color: red;
}

td {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: dotted;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:751px) {
  .table_details {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Cars</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">GM</a><span class="link_company">GM & </span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">VW</a><span class="link_company">VW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">BMW</a><span class="link_company">BMW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Citroen</a><span class="link_company">Citroen</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Fruits</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Apple</a><span class="link_company">Apple</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Banana</a><span class="link_company">Banana</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Plump</a><span class="link_company">Plump</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: I know there is no javascript tag in the post, but having this dynamically adapt to the content is impossible by current css standards (nth-match will solve this in future, but that is conventionally unusable at this moment)